# Least squares with an idempotent matrix

Tags: inverse, least-squares, idempotents

This question is mainly to confirm my intuition (since my proof is counter intuititive).

Suppose I have a least squares formulation, $AX=B$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$ (here n < d).

I want to solve for $X$, but here is the catch $A$ is both idempotent and singular.  So not invertible.  And the pseudo-inverse isn't clearly defined either since $A^TA = A$ is also singular.

I try to take advantage of the idempotent property and do the following

$AX = B$

$AAX = AB$

$AX = AB$

$A(X-B) = 0$

which will give tell me that $X=B$.  This also implies that $AB = B$.

This doesn't seem quite right to me, would love to hear anyone's thoughts on this.

EDIT: thanks to @Qiaochu Yuan, its clear why the above proof is wrong.  The follow up question is, does $X$ have a well-defined solution?

Comment: If $A$ is singular then you can't cancel $A$ from $A(X - B)$.

Comment: Not canceling A here.  If A(X-B) = 0, then that means either A=0 or X-B=0.  From the problem definition, we know what A (so $A \neq 0$), which means that X-B=0.

Comment: That's what I mean by "canceling $A$" and that isn't true for matrices. Note that if it were true then it would be impossible for $A$ to be a nontrivial idempotent: we have $AA = IA$ where $I$ is the identity, so $A(I - A) = 0$ but it doesn't follow that $A = 0$ or $A = I$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for clarifying, that makes sense (and clarifies why my proof is wrong).  The follow up question is, does X have a well defined solution?

Comment: Do you mean a least squares solution, i.e. a value of $X$ that minimizes $\| AX - B \|$? Yes, this always exists.